# Javascript undefined behavior with string.replace

Tags: javascript, undefined-behavior

I've been messing around with string.replace and I noticed something very odd with Webkit and Firebug's javascript consoles.

I can repeat this behavior in a blank browser window. (Look at the first and last lines)

```
>>> "/literature?page=".replace(/page=/i, "page=2")
"/literature?page="

>>> "/literature?page=".replace("page=", "page=2")
"/literature?page=2"

>>> "/literature?page=".replace(/page=/, "page=2")
"/literature?page=2"

>>> "/literature?page=".replace(/page=/i, "page=2")
"/literature?page=2"
```

Just so nobody thinks I mistyped something, here are screenshots.

**Firebug (3.0.14)**

[image: firefbug]

**Webkit (Latest nightly as of this post's creation.)**

[image: webkit]

Comment: Just to be clear, it seems you are highlighting an example where you run a command two different times w/ 2 different results?

Comment: Firefox 3.6.3. Mine behaves as expected, not as yours has.

Comment: I've confirmed Firefox 3.6.3 behaves correctly. The problem is, I still have to work around this behavior with other browsers.

Comment: I've figured out this behavior is not always reproducible with Safari and Firefox but with enough playing around I can reproduce the behavior but repeating the same series of commands doesn't always produce the bug. (Possible background behavior messing with the JS engine)

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Firefox 3.5.9, Firefox 3.6.3, IE7, Chrome 3, Safari 4, Opera 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome I get the final result the first time.
[See the image here.](http://imagebin.org/94260)